# Block Internet access Win10 VM

Tags: hyper-v, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 10 Hyper-V VM and need to block all Internet access, but only leave access so I can connect via RDP.
Right now, I just went into Internet Options and set the Proxy to the loopback IP. It works for now, but wanted to know another way via the Win10 Firewall and/or the Hyper-V swtich.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I wrote that I set the proxy to 127.0.0.1....

Comment: Setting the proxy settings is known not to prevent internet access. Right now you're focusing on the VM as a discrete system and have ignored the options based on the fact this is a VM. You should look into modifying the Hyperv network settings the VM is connected to.